# datepicker date is not show by select box value

Tags: ajax, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have created a function and call this function in select input inside another ajex file, when ajex is calling then and I want to get option value and set this value in API URL after`your text`

call function in ajex file

```
<select class="form-control m-bot15"  name="trainer_name"  onchange="show()" id='select' required>
    <option value="">Select Trainer</option>
    <option value="5">Select Trainer</option>
<option value="6">Select Trainer</option>     
    </select>

let initialize = true;
  let select = document.getElementById('select')
  let list = [];

abcd();
select.addEventListener('change',function(){
    abcd()
})

// console.log(abcd());
function abcd(){
   fetch(`apu_url=${select.value}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => list = data)
    .finally(show)
}

function show() {
    let dates = list.filter(d => d.trainerid == select.value).map(e=>e.date_dmy_for)
    let config = {
            multidate: true,
            startDate: new Date(),
            minDate: new Date(),
            weekStart: 1,
            format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
            //daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
            language: 'en',
            bound: false,
            //daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
                var search_index = $.inArray(dmy, dates);

                if (search_index > -1) {
                    return { classes: 'non-highlighted-cal-dates', tooltip: 'student have batch on this day.' };
                } else {
                    return { classes: '', tooltip: 'student available on this day.' };
                }

        }
        
    }
    if(!initialize) $('.date').datepicker("destroy");
    $('.date').datepicker(config);
  initialize = false;

}
```

I want to when ajex file is calling then I select option value calendar data change accoring to option value